# Can you construct a hypersphere with a curvature of zero?

Tags: geometry, curvature, 4-manifolds

Is it possible to construct a four-dimensional hypersphere where every point on the surface is equidistant from the center, yet with all three of the surface dimension being orthogonal to each other and the radius?  Also, the radius is some finite value and -- according the data I'm trying to interpret -- the size of the circumference of the sphere appears to be a function of the radius.  That is, is it possible to construct a four-dimensional hypersphere with a curvature of 0?  If so, what would you call it?

Comment: Most likely the answer to your question is NO. But, depending on your definition of "curvature" and on the space in which your sphere sits, there might be room for exploration.

Answer (score 0):

It would be just like one dimension down.  A plane is in a sense the limit of a sphere as the radius runs off to infinity.  The two axes in the plane are perpendicular to the radius.  If you accept this as a construction, it works.  In four dimensions you would have a three space that works the same way, being a limit of a hypersphere as the radius goes to infinity.  That is useful for some purposes, but you need to be careful to justify the construction in your use.

Comment: The data I have indicates that the radius would be large, but finite.  Also, the three surface dimensions appear to be functions of the radius.

Comment: Note that a sphere in three space satisfies everything you are asking for except the curvature of zero.  The curvature is the inverse of the radius.  Nothing changes in 4D.  What data are you speaking of?

Comment: The data is SNe Ia magnitude data.  It fits better to a 4-d hypersphere than one defined by FLRW.  My biggest issue is the curvature which we know to be very close to zero.

Comment: If you were to slice the Earth along the arctic circle, then measure the circle created by lopping off the top of the world, you'd find a circle that was smaller than $2\pi R$ (that is, $C = 2\pi R \sin\theta$) .  It seems to me that $C=2\pi R$ is an attribute of Cartesian space. Is it possible to work in higher dimensions where the diameter of the 'sphere' is not the product of the diameter and $\pi$?

Comment: The circumference of a hypersphere is $\pi$ times the diameter in any Euclidean space, regardless of dimension.  It is not in non-Euclidean spaces because the overall space has curvature.  I think you are mixing up space curvature and the curvature of the hypersphere as embedded in Euclidean space.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: I'm sure I'm mixing ideas.  I'm starting from the data and working my way backwards to try and find the right foundation.  Is there a geometric construct where the 'surface' can be the square of the 'radius' and all points on the 'surface' are equidistant from a 'center'.

Comment: A normal 2-sphere has area $4\pi R^2$ and has all its points equidistant from a center.

Comment: Sorry, when I said surface, I was talking about the circumference.  The SNe Ia data indicates a shape where the 'circumference' (the total amount of space) is a function of the square of the 'radius' (time) ($s = t^2$).  Is there kind of higher-level geometry that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71018/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-mike-doonsebury).